# Stumped on how mainform - subform1 - subform2 handles what record shows when subform1 becomes the active form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, subform

I have a mainform (Cruises) with a subform (DiveSites) which itself has several other subforms (Notes, Samples, Photos)

My user can interact with the Notes subform to add dive notes (New button) and start and end transects (Start and End buttons), among other things.  Transects are just paths followed along the seafloor that have a start lat/lon/depth and an end lat/lon/depth.  The application should maintain a running list of transect numbers for the entire cruise.

I keep the last used transect number in the Cruises table so that whenever the user starts a new transect in that cruise, it will look up the last used transect number and then add 1 to set the new transect number.

The Start button is the only case where I lose my place in the DiveSites form when that form gets the focus again.  It resets back to the first DiveSites record for that form.

I think it must be because in that code, I have to open the Cruises recordset and look up that transect number. Other than that, the code for the other buttons is very similar and doesn't cause the reset to the first record.

I have not used Bookmarks before and am having trouble finding an example of how those work for these nested forms and applying that to my situation.

```
Private Sub StartTransect_Click()
' when a new transect is started, set the XS# to the next available transect number for this operation (saved in the Cruise Information table) and read the putty_log for the latest location and depth
Dim db As Database
Dim puttylog As Recordset
Dim CruiseInfo As Recordset
Dim currcruise As String
Dim templat, templon, tempdepth As String
Dim msg As String
Dim response As Variant

' first set up the environment and open the putty_log recordset to read the submersible current lat/lon/depth
' also open the Cruise Information table as a recordset to read in the lasttransect number
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set puttylog = db.OpenRecordset("putty_log")
Set CruiseInfo = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation", dbOpenDynaset)
msg = "You must end the previous transect before starting a new one"

If transectstarted Then
    response = MsgBox(msg, vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ESub
       
Else
    transectstarted = True
    currcruise = Forms!Frm_tbl_Cruise_Form!CruiseID
    CruiseInfo.FindFirst "CruiseID = '" & currcruise & "'"
    lasttransect = CruiseInfo!lastTransectNum
    TransectNumber = lasttransect + 1
   
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me!Transect_Number = TransectNumber
    Me!ExtraNote_ID = Me!DiveNote_ID
    Me!Date_Time_Notes = Now()
    Me!TransectStartStop = "Photo XS- Start: " & Now()
    templat = Str(puttylog![lat_GPRMC])
    templon = Str(puttylog![lon_GPRMC])
    tempdepth = Str(puttylog!Depth)
    Me!Latitude = Format(templat, "0000.0000")
    Me!Longitude = Format(templon, "00000.0000")
    Me!Depth = Format(tempdepth, "0000.0")

    CruiseInfo.Edit
    CruiseInfo!lastTransectNum = TransectNumber
    CruiseInfo.Update
End If

ESub:
' reset the recordset and database to nothing to release it

Set CruiseInfo = Nothing
Set puttylog = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Opening a recordset should not cause form to return to first record. Why do you think you need Bookmark? Why does putty_log recordset not have filter criteria? Why would two fields in same dataset have same value (Me!ExtraNote_ID = Me!DiveNote_ID)? Really should not save last transect number in CruiseInfo - should just retrieve that from Notes when needed. Instead of CruiseInfo recordset could probably use DMax() domain aggregate function.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am not the developer of the database, but rather have been called in to help with adding some vba for controlling some logic.  The developer is not a vba programmer.  I don't know what the use of the ExtraNote is and was going to ask the developer about that.  Unfortunately, I am a self-taught vba programmer and so I often do not know how things work exactly - especially event triggering and the state of things.  In doing online research I just find there seems to be so many ways to "skin a cat" so to speak.  I will look into your suggestions.  I appreciate you.

Comment: This application is used for multiple cruises so I need to maintain the last used transect number in the cruises table so that when the user selects a cruise, the application will know where they left off.  The putty_log is just a snapshot of the current lat/lon/depth of the submersible that is maintained on a 1 sec frequency.  I need the application to look up those values whenever a button is pressed in the dive notes (e.g. on/off bottom, start/end transect, etc) My trouble is that the divesites form resets to the first cruise when I go back to it only after I've used the Start button.

Comment: I don't see anything in code to cause that and would have to analyze db. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db.